# ActiveRecord ISessionFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net, activerecord

I'm trying use ActiveRecord but I want get ISessionFactory and today I can not get this with AR. How I can get SessionFactory using AR?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Reference NHibernate in your project and then import it in your code.